# RSpec generate request spec instead of controller spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using rspec-rails but I'd like to change when `rails g controller Blahs` is invoked, I'd like spec/requests/ to be created, instead of spec/controllers/.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

```
rails g integration_test foo
```

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 6):

Seems like there is no usual way to achieve this, however I've found monkey-patching solution:

```
# config/initializers/generators.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.generators do |g|
    # your setup here, like g.javascripts = false
  end

  def self.load_generators(*)
    super
    require 'rails/generators/rails/controller/controller_generator'
    Rails::Generators::ControllerGenerator.class_eval do
      remove_hook_for :test_framework
      hook_for :test_framework, as: :request
    end
  end
end
```

Here is some explanation: hook for test framework is set right inside ControllerGenerator, so we need to load the class to override the value. I don't want to load this class in any case other than running generators. `config.generators` block runs for console and server too, so it's not appropriate. There is also `self.generators` block, but it runs before `config.generators` and generator will be not configured. So I've found `Engine#load_generators` method, which fits for me.

Tested with rails 5.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

There is a RSpec generator to generate request specs:

```
rails g rspec:request Foo
```

Note that in order to enable RSpec generators you need to place the following code in your `application.rb`:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  config.generators do |g|
    g.test_framework :rspec
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually configure this but you can always fork rspec-rails and tweak it to your liking https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/controller/controller_generator.rb

Good luck!

Comment: I was afraid that this might be an answer =P